# Checking for vowels in the following array of pointers to strings?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
main()
{
    char *a[]={"FrIiends is an american television sitcom",    //*line to be checked*
                "created by David crane and marta kauffman",
                "which originally aired on NBC"};
    int i=0,len=0,j=0,count=0;                            //Initialization of certain variables
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        count=0;                    //Count always made 0 for new line
        len=strlen(*(a+i));         //Lenght for new line is stored here every time
        for(j=0;j<len;j++){           
                if((int)*(*(a+i)+j)==97 || (int)*(*(a+i)+j)==101 || (int)*(*(a+i)+j)==105 || (int)*(*(a+i)+j)==111 || (int)*(*(a+i)+j)==117) //checking for vowels in lowercase
                    count=count +1;
                if ((int)*(*(a+i)+j)==65 || (int)*(*(a+i)+j)==69 || (int)*(*(a+i)+j)==73 || (int)*(*(a+i)+j)==79 || (int)*(*(a+i)+j)==85) //checking for vowels in Uppercase
                    count=count+1;
        }
         printf("Vowels in line %d are:%d\n",i+1,count);  //Final print statement


    }

}
```

The following code works fine,but is there an alternate way to count vowels in the following pointer to arrays?
It also seems rather inefficient to use.
In my case above i made huge test cases for both upper and lower case.Is there a way to ignore case or anything similar.

Comment: Don't use "magic numbers" for characters, use the actual character literals (like e.g. `'a'`). You could also use `tolower` (or `toupper`) so you only have one check. And please do use array-indexing syntax instead of pointer arithmetics, it will make the code easier to read as well.

Comment: Were you taught this notation `(int)*(*(a+i)+j)` or did you make it up by yourself? Consider using `a[i][j]` instead.

Comment: @Jongware i will make sure to avoid using these `(int)*(*(a+i)+j)` notations as much as possible. Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void){
    char *a[]={"FrIiends is an american television sitcom",
                "created by David crane and marta kauffman",
                "which originally aired on NBC"};
    char *p, ch;
    int i, count;
    for(i=0; i<3; ++i){
        count=0;
        p = *(a + i);//a[i];
        while(ch=tolower(*p++)){
            if(ch=='e' || ch=='a' || ch=='i' || ch=='o' || ch=='u')
                ++count;
        }
        printf("Vowels in line %d are:%d\n", i+1, count);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why `*(a + i)` and not `a[i]`?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I tailored to the OP.

Comment: writing `*(a + i)` instead of `a[i]` will hardly ever help him…

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I agree.